# versions-maven-plugin doesn't retrieve the latest version on nexus?

Tags: versioning, maven-plugin, pom.xml, versions-maven-plugin

I am trying to use (partly successfully) the **versions-maven-plugin** to retrieve latest release/snapshot versions from my local **and** nexus repositories to update maven projects. When running this plugin to update versions, I have noticed the following behaviour:

Even though I know that there is a newer version in nexus, but not in my local repository, it doesn't find the latest version, but the latest from the local repo. If I delete all the maven-metadata*.xml files from my local repo for the artifact I want to update, it downloads the latest maven-metadata*.xml files and correctly finds the latest version.

I see that it's using **2.0.6** og all maven APIs, and the method that drives the whole update mechanism is **retrieveAvailableVersions()** from interface **ArtifactMetadataSource** and implemented by **MavenMetadataSource**.

**MY QUESTION**
How can I alter the code of this plugin to always download the latest maven-metadata*.xml files such that I get the latest versions? Or if there is any other **reliable** method which can make this happen..

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually found the solution myself and created a goal which I run before running goals which updates my pom.xml files: This is the method which updates the metadata for all repositories. If you need the whole goals, please let me know:

```
 public void updateMetadata(Artifact artifact){        
    getLog().info("Updating metadata for: " + artifact.getGroupId()+":"+artifact.getArtifactId());
    RepositoryMetadata metadata = new ArtifactRepositoryMetadata( artifact);    
    for ( Iterator<ArtifactRepository> repo = remoteArtifactRepositories.iterator(); repo.hasNext(); ){
        ArtifactRepository repository = repo.next();            
        ArtifactRepositoryPolicy policy = 
                metadata.isSnapshot() ? repository.getSnapshots() : repository.getReleases();
        File file = new File( localRepository.getBasedir(), 
                localRepository.pathOfLocalRepositoryMetadata( metadata, repository ) );
        getLog().info("Updating " + repository.getBasedir());            
        try {
            wagonManager.getArtifactMetadata( metadata, repository, file, policy.getChecksumPolicy());
            getLog().info("Updated...");
        } catch (TransferFailedException e) {
            getLog().info("Couldn't find " +  metadata + " from repository: " + repository.getId() +
                    "\n Reason\n: " + e.getMessage() );
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ResourceDoesNotExistException e) {
            getLog().info("Cannot find " +  metadata + " in repository: " + repository.getId() );
            if ( file.exists() ){
                file.delete();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```